# PHP - finfo_file returns incorrect MIME type

Tags: php, mime-types

I have an application which i can upload/download files with different format. When i upload i have the correct MIME type, but when i download the same file, finfo_file of PHP returns me an incorrect MIME type. Here is some values that i got :

Code :

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
echo $mime_type;
```

Output :

```
application/msword // test0.pot INCORRECT should be application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
text/plain // test1.csv ICNORRECT should be text/csv
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint // test2.pptx INCORRECT should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
application/msword // test3.pps INCORRECT should be application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
application/msword // test4.docx INCORRECT should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
application/msword // test5.doc CORRECT
application/vnd.ms-excel // test6.xls CORRECT
application/vnd.ms-excel // test7.xlsx INCORRECT should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
application/msword // test8.docm INCORRECT should be application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12
application/pdf // test9.pdf CORRECT
```

I checked apache's mime.types file, mime types are correct. Is there an another configuration that i have to do ? Can someone help me to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, some formats cannot be distinguished from others. A CSV is also a perfectly valid `text/plain`, there's no technical difference. *Detecting* types is by definition an inaccurate science.

Comment: When i download a .csv file, it's not ergonomic to open it with Bloc notes. By default the chosen application must be Excel to read it and for powerpoint presentations it should be ms PowerPoint not ms word. I mean, that's what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this and it works better now :

Code :

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, "conf/magic");
$myMime = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
```

Thanks anyway.